# Changing wordpress admin url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, capistrano

I have a wordpress site that was deployed using Capistrano.

The front end works but when i access the wp-admin/ page there are some error on my url,

`http://www.youthrive.com.au/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youthrive.com.au%2Fcurrent%2Ftrunk%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1`

I want to remove current/trunk on the url. Is there a way achieving that using htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not via .htaccess you can change this via wp-config.php and functions.php of theme

wp-config.php

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

functions.php

```
update_option( 'siteurl', 'http://example.com' );
update_option( 'home', 'http://example.com' );
```

Replace the URL you need to change.

Comment: no i am not trying to change the url i am just trying to remove /current/trunk to wp-admin. please see the entire url

Comment: If that URL stored in your database , you can just click on save and update permalinks to do that , it will work.

Comment: no its not save in the database it is generatd by htaccess

Comment: you can try updating the permalinks or add rewrite rule to change that..